# Display pihole API information on Nokia 5110

Tags: python, pi-3

I want to use the Nokia 5110 screen to display my stats from pihole. I'm not sure if it's able to be done. The screen is able to display starts from pimonitor so I'm assuming it would be able to display the API info from pihole. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you have a way to connect to the screen? A driver? Documentation? Probably not going to happen.

Comment: The screen is able to connect through gpio, and I'm able to get a display as well.. I just don't know how to get the info from pihole to display on the screen. Right now I can basically put text for it to display and that's it. I just don't know how to make that text the info from pihole.